# Is it possible (legal) to assign an anonymous union in a compound literal?

Tags: c, c99, unions, compound-literals

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct _n
{
    int type;
    union {
        char *s;
        int i;
    };
} n;
```

When I try to assign a compound literal, like:

```
node n1 = {1, 0};
node n2 = {2, "test"};
```

gcc gives me some warnings such as:

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Well, it's clear that the compiler isn't sure about me just assigning a value to a possibly ambiguous type.  However, even if I try to specify more precisely:

```
node n0 = {type: 1, i: 4};
```

I get:

```
error: unknown field ‘i’ specified in initializer
```

I have read that if I put `(union <union name>)` before `i:` then it may work.  However, I prefer having an anonymous union.  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anonymous unions are not standard C -- they are a compiler extension.  I would strongly recommend giving the union a name.  If you insist on using an anonymous union, then you can only give an initializer for the first element of it:

```
node n0 = {1, 0};  // initializes `s' to 0
```

When compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, gcc gave me the warning "missing braces around initializer", which is a valid warning.  The initializer should actually be specified like this:

```
node n0 = {1, {0}};  // initializes `s' to 0
```

Now this only gives a warning that "ISO C doesn't support unnamed structs/unions".

If you give the union a name, then you can use a C99 feature called *designated initializers* to initialize a specific member of the union:

```
typedef struct
{
    int type;
    union {
        char *s;
        int i;
    } value;
} node;

node n0 = {1, { .s = "string" }};
node n1 = {2, { .i = 123 }};
```

You need the union to have a name; otherwise, the compiler will complain about the designated initializer inside it.

The syntax you were trying to use `node n0 = {type: 1, i: 4}` is invalid syntax; it looks like you were trying to use designated initializers.

Comment: It surprised me the first time I saw it, but to GCC that's actually legal (though deprecated) designated initializer syntax.

Comment: that (i guess deprecated) initializer syntax i got from reading some kernel module code.. 'fops' structures are often written that way.  i'll switch to the C99 way now.  Too bad about anonymous unions, I didn't know they were not standard, thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a `;` after `123` or `"string"` ? It doesn’t compile for me with it. It compiles without it.

Comment: @chmike: Whoops, not sure why I did that 11 years ago—you're right, there should not be semicolons in there.  Fixed now.